# Как правильно передать параметры в скрипт с помощью командной строки

Tags: python, функции, консоль, импорт

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Значение `python try.py 1 3` запускаю в терминале. Выдает  `C:\Users\`.

```
import sys


def summ(one, two):
    print(one + two)


try:
    one = int(sys.argv[1])
    two = int(sys.argv[2])

    summ(one, two)

except:
    raise ValueError("No required attributes")
```

Comment: у меня  запуск `python try.py 1 3` выдает `4`

Comment: @S.Nick может мне не хватает какой-то программы?

Comment: `where python` что выдает?

Comment: @extrn C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

Comment: Ну тогда последний вопрос: `type try.py` выдает именно тот текст программы, который вы приложили?

Comment: @extrn кажется нет: bash: type: try.py: not found

Comment: bash? ну тогда `cat try.py` или `more try.py`

Comment: @extrn cat: try.py: No such file or directory

Comment: Ну значит ваш try.py находится в другом замке. Указывайте до него полный путь или перенесите в папку, откуда запускаете python. `explorer .` откроет ее